# c open() Undefined error: 0 on os x

Tags: c, macos, serial-port

On a mac running 10.8 i am trying to open a serial port.

ls /dev/cu* returns:

```
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem     /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync  /dev/cu.usbserial-A1009TT7
```

i can see the port is there but when i try to open it i get Undefined error: 0(0). This is my code i use to open the port.

```
char *path = "/dev/cu.usbserial-A1009TT7";

open(path , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);     // open the port

if (file == -1) {
    printf("Error opening port : %s(%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    close(file);
    return -1;
}
```

anyone have any idea why the port wont open?

thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a typo or did you miss to assign the return value from `open()` to `file`?

Comment: Ehr, you don't actually save the return value from the `open` call.

Comment: As well as the above comments, you `close()` an unopened file descriptor?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops!  You meant to type this:

```
file = open(path , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
^^^^^^^
```

Also, there is no need to close a file descriptor that isn't open.

```
if (file == -1) {
    printf(...);
    // close(file); Completely unnecessary.  It's not valid!
    return -1;
}
```